# Is it possible to host the same WCF on more than one application (windows service) controlled by using differing endpoints or some similar idea?

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint

Is it possible to host the same WCF on more than one application (or windows service) controlled by using differing endpoints or some similar idea?

Basically we need up to 4 versions of the same Windows service running (e.g. Service1... Service4) using and hosting the same WCF dll but picking up requests from clients to a specific Service?.

For example: I need the ability for a client to ask "one" of the Service? hosts to perform a calculation routine - maybe with multiple endpoints?..

```
        Consume.ServiceRef.WCFServiceClient obj = new Consume.ServiceRef.WCFServiceClient("Service1");


        bool res = obj.ProcessCalc(out response, out error, request);
```

Another client may request from a differing host...

```
Consume.ServiceRef.WCFServiceClient obj = new Consume.ServiceRef.WCFServiceClient("Service3");
```

All hosts perform the same functions but I need multiple hosts due to some complications with third-party software and business requirements.

I have done this before (20 years back) myself using sockets (and self handled multi-threading) on a DEC VMS server but would like to use WCF for it's ease of use.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible with simple configuration changes , one of the major advantage in WCF.

see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/configuring-multiple-end-points-for-wcf-service/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can set up your endpoints in the configuration and have the service select which binding to use. You could use command line parameters or service parameters to choose which endpoint to use for the instance.

Comment: Could you give some simple examples. I have tried the multiple endpoints but it complains that only one host is allowed for each base address etc even when the endpoints are differing names - all endpoints will use the same configuration etc just need differing names.